# Function called multiple times in Codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, xdebug

I have this code in my CI controller.

```
public function edit($id = '') 
{

    $this->load->helper("form");
    $this->load->library("form_validation");
    $data["title"] = "Edit category";

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category_name', 'Category name', 'required');

    if (!$this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $data['category'] = $this->categories_model->get_categories($id);
        $this->load->view("templates/admin_header", $data);
        $this->load->view("categories/edit", $data);
        $this->load->view("templates/admin_footer", $data); 
    }
    else
    {
        $this->categories_model->update($id);
        // other logic
    }
}
```

If the form is submited, it updates the category. If I load the page /categories/edit/32 it shows me the info for the category.

I develop with Netbeans and XDebug. My problem here is that when I put a break point on the first line of the function, the debugger returns three times on the break point. I load the page /categories/edit/32 and the debugger stops at the first line om the break point. I press F5 to continue, it loads the function for the second time. I press F5 again, it loads the function for the third and last time. What can cause this? Is this some bug in Netbeans or XDebug, or I have some bug that I can't see?

EDIT:

I have this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|include|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I've found that the problem is in one jQuery plugin that preloads all the images from all the css files. All the images that are preloaded are inside the images folder. If I remove the plugin, it works fine.

Comment: Have you been able to step along until execution returns to the breakpoint?

Comment: do line-by-line then you can find out why the function is called three times. and ensure you don't press F5 in the browser. just saying.

Comment: @Sam Dufel: I don't understand what you mean by "step along" :) But to be more clear, the page loads OK after the function is called three times. I only noticed this when I put the break point inside the function, otherwise it is working fine and fast. What I don't understand is what is the cause of this, why is the function called three times?

Comment: you can enable logs from config file in CI, if some class or method is called 3 times you will be able to check inside logs i think, try it

Comment: I've edited my initial post with the.htaccess file that I use.